# Compare two lists of unequal lengths and remove partial matches?

Tags: java, list

Lets say I have two lists like:

```
List1 = Fulton Tax Commissioner 's Office, Grady Hospital, Fulton Health Department

List2 = Atlanta Police Department, Fulton Tax Commissioner, Fulton Health Department,Grady Hospital
```

I want my final list to look like this:

```
Final List = Fulton Tax Commissioner 's Office,Grady Hospital,Fulton Health Department,Atlanta Police Department
```

I can remove duplicates from these lists by adding both the lists to a set. But how do I remove partial matches like Fulton Tax Commissioner?

Comment: I've already seen this question before

Comment: @Andremoniy I'm using the same example but the context is different.

Comment: What do you mean by "partial matches"?

Comment: Would "Abcdefg" and "def" be a partial match? Would "Fulton DayCare Center" and "Fulton Health Department" be matches? Or must one be fully contained in the other? Like "Fulton Health" and "Fulton Health Department" - in that case which of the two shall be kicked out?

Comment: Please explain by giving at least two examples, what is meant by partial match. If beginning say N characters match then its partial match or is there a different criteria.

Comment: @Fildor Sorry for answering this late. To answer your questions, partial match means Fulton Health and Fulton Health Department. Fulton Day Care Center and Fulton Health Department will be separate entities. So you idea is correct that  one must be fully contained in the other and if it is then the string that contains it stays and the shorter string gets kicked out as it is assumed that the entire entity name was not captured properly in this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest: Set the result to a copy of list 1. For each member of list 2:

- If the result contains the same member, skip it.
- If the result contains a member that starts with the list 2 member, also skip the list 2 member
- If the result contains a member that is a prefix of the list 2 member, replace it by the list 2 member
- Otherwise add the list 2 member to the result.

If using Java 8, the tests in the 2nd and 3rd bullets can be conveniently done with streams, for example `result.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.startsWith(list2Member));`.

There is room for optimization, for example using a `TreeSet` (if it’s OK to sort the items).

Edit: In Java:

```
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(list1);
    for (String list2Member : list2) {
        if (result.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.startsWith(list2Member))) { // includes case where list2Member is in result
            // skip
        } else {
            OptionalInt resultIndex = IntStream.range(0, result.size())
                    .filter(ix -> list2Member.startsWith(result.get(ix)))
                    .findAny();
            if (resultIndex.isPresent()) {
                result.set(resultIndex.getAsInt(), list2Member);
            } else {
                result.add(list2Member);
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
[Fulton Tax Commissioner 's Office, Grady Hospital, Fulton Health Department, Atlanta Police Department]
```

I believe this exactly the result you asked for.

Further edit: In Java 9 you may use (not tested):

```
            resultIndex.ifPresentOrElse(ix -> result.set(ix, list2Member), () -> result.add(list2Member));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to set by passing a comparator, like below:

```
Set s = new TreeSet(new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // add the logic to say that partial match is considered same.
    }
});
s.addAll(yourList);
```

Comment: "the logic to say that partial match is considered same" is the tricky part I guess.

Comment: Existing libraries can be used to do that based on the requirement, for example StringUtils from apace commons has Levenshtein algorithm related methods, they can be used to find smiliar strings.